# Get selected value of jQuery dropdown plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using [**jQuery dropdown**](http://dane.one/projects/jquery-dropdown/) plugin and I want to get selected `value`, but there is no such option in docs, How can I get selected value via jQuery?

```js
(function($) {

  $(function() {

    $('ul').dropdown({
      closeReset: false,
      nested: true,
      collision: true,
      selectParents: true
    });

  });

}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-dropdown/2.0.3/jquery.dropdown.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dane.one/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/dropdown.min_.css?ver=7e2962cd876e2a95be90b37baa97b096" type="text/css" />
<ul>
  <li>group 1
    <ul>
      <li>assest 1
        <ul>
          <li>bingo!</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>group 2
    <ul>
      <li>assest 2
        <ul>
          <li>bingo!</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Also this problem asked before in [github](https://github.com/daneWilliams/jquery.dropdown/issues/29) but no answer.
Look like the plugin not working on this snippet, please see demos **[here](http://dane.one/projects/jquery-dropdown/demo/)** (I'm using Nested demo)

Note that, I'm using `ul` not `select option`

Comment: @Axnyff , No that not plugin I'm using.

Comment: Oops sorry. The problem for the moment with your snippet is that some ressources you're trying to load are in http and the browser won't allow it as stackoverflow is in https. Find some publicly hosted version of your lib and it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@CodeSavy** answer is in the right direction and logic but got some issue. if the creator did not provide an option to get selected value you should do this on your own, open `jquery.dropdown.js` search for `var classes = {` you'll find this `selected: 'dropdown-selected',` so after select each item it will add this class to selected item. in the previous answer you get all items `text()` after `click` but below you can get only *selected* item `text()`

```
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-item', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('dropdown-selected')) {
    var val = $(this).text();
    console.log(val);
  }
})
```

*But with some change on plugin script you can add some attribute or value to get better result.*

Answer (score 1):

Care to use `select`? **[documentation](http://dane.one/projects/jquery-dropdown/docs/#initialising)** used `select` not `ul`. That way, you can get selected value. **Can't comment so will post here**

**Updated answer:** here's how to get the selected

```
var selectedValue = '';
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu li.dropdown-item', function(e) {
    selectedValue = $(this).find('span').text();
});
```

Comment: I'm using `nested` mode, so I should use `ul` because I'm using multi level drop down.

Comment: Documentaion has both select and ul. Select is primary

Comment: i see, can you give me link to the example? I inspected element of `nested demo` & it uses `select`

Comment: Yes, because on that demo it used only two level, and used `optgroup` and `option` but I have 5 level almost. okay let me upload it somewhere.

Comment: i found the UL usage example, please try updated answer @tourtravel & please mark as accepted answer & upvote if it works for you so I can also upvote :)

Comment: @CodeSavy But it should using with a even, like click, change or etc.. click on what? or change what? I'm confused

Comment: i played around with the dropdown & i think it would be best if we go with `click` event. let me update answer

Comment: @tourtravel can you try again mate?